# why am i getting ~ no response on stdout ~ in hacker rank nodejs

Tags: node.js

Please who knows how to run a function  with stdin and stdout on hackerrank for example

```
function getPrimes(n){

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // for each i...

  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { // look for a divisor..
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; // not a prime, go next i
  }

 console.log(i) ; // a prime
}
}
```

then use process. stdin and stdout function to display the result

Comment: Can you link to the page?

Comment: please view the  screenshot here [link](https://ibb.co/TTG4Bzd)

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/4pqkibpt5t0/questions/3obkc4assfh

Comment: It seems like a company interview challenge. From what I can see before starting the test there is a [Sample Test](https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/sample) link. Which is pretty useful if you're not familiar with Hackerrank UI. There are also 2 email addresses where you can ask for support in case you have a trouble during the challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at how the function you're writing is being used. For example, with `getPrimes`, look for other uses of `getPrimes` in the HackerRank *built-in* code. For example, from the [sample test](https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/sample/questions/3lpcngf4s90), there is a question asking me to complete a `findNumber` function:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function(inputStdin) {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.split('\n');

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}



// Complete the findNumber function below.
function findNumber(arr, k) {

}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const arrCount = parseInt(readLine().trim(), 10);

    let arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrCount; i++) {
        const arrItem = parseInt(readLine().trim(), 10);
        arr.push(arrItem);
    }

    const k = parseInt(readLine().trim(), 10);

    const res = findNumber(arr, k);

    ws.write(res + '\n');

    ws.end();
}
```

The function `findNumber` is being called in the line

```
const res = findNumber(arr, k);
```

with its return value assigned to `res`. **If the called function's return value is used, you should probably always return a value**. Otherwise, if it's not being used, eg if the line was just

```
findNumber(arr, k);
```

then the return value is ignored, so your output will probably be determined by what you call `console.log` with.

In your case, you should *probably* `return` a value from `getPrimes` so that HR can parse it. Not sure what the challenge is asking for, but maybe something like

```
function getPrimes(n) {
  const arrOfPrimes = [];
  nextPrime: for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // for each i...

    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { // look for a divisor..
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; // not a prime, go next i
    }

    arrOfPrimes.push(i);
  }
  return arrOfPrimes;
}
```

or something along those lines - just make sure something is being `return`ed at the end, if the result of the `getPrimes` call is being used somewhere.

Comment: what if it like this

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what if the main function is like this    
  let main = () => {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    let res = [];
    let gen = getPrimes(n);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let val = gen.next().value;
        if (val == undefined)
            break;
        res.push(val);
    }

    ws.write(res.join("\n") + "\n");

    ws.end();
}

Comment: Sounds like it's expecting `gen` to be an iterator: have `getPrimes` be a generator function, and `yield` each value instead. (on a side note, that's a very confusing variable name on the part of HR - they shouldn't call an *iterator* `gen`, that makes it sound like a generator, which it's not)

Comment: Thanks a lot i just changed the function getPrimes(n)  to  function * getPrimes(n) and it works

Answer (score 28):

Hackerrank documentations haven't mentioned this.

This is how it worked for me.

```
// It will work on Javscript(nodejs), not sure about others
fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH).write("Your Output");
```

Answer (score 3):

For me just write worked for me:

```
process.stdout.write("some answer")
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `ws.write(result.join(' ') + '\n');` with `ws.write(result.toString())`